# Upload image to firebase storage with different sizes

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am new in this field. I need to upload one image and resize it (small(h:100,w:100), medium(h:200,w:200),
(large(h:300,w:300)) and store this three different sized images to firebase storage.

My code: It uploads one image and store it to firebase storage. No more!!!

[Above html form with input file and button onclick=uploadimage()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CG8Xh.png)

Can you help me please!!!

Comment: Please include your code as text rather than an image, and include any traceback errors

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Firebase extension dedicated to images resize: https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/storage-resize-images

> Use this extension to create resized versions of an image uploaded to
> a Cloud Storage bucket.
>
> When you upload an image file to your specified Cloud Storage bucket,
> this extension:
>
> - Creates a resized image with your specified dimensions.
> - Names the resized image using the same name as the original uploaded image, but suffixed with your specified width and height.
> - Stores the resized image in the same Storage bucket as the original uploaded image.
>
> You can even configure the extension to create resized images of
> different dimensions for each original image upload. For example, you
> might want images that are 200x200, 400x400, and 680x680 - this
> extension can create these three resized images then store them in
> your bucket.

Comment: Is there any way to set different resize option for different folder?

Comment: @Unknown2433 You can deploy several instances of the same extension with a different configuration. Since you can configure the sizes of resized images and the path that contain images you want to resize it should do the trick.

Comment: Can I use file name in path? For example `/rooms/*/0.jpg` will resize `0.jpg` file?

Comment: @Unknown2433 I don't think so. But I may be wrong: you should give a try!

Comment: More details in the [doc](https://github.com/firebase/extensions/tree/master/storage-resize-images): "Restrict storage-resize-images to only resize **images in specific locations** in your Storage bucket by supplying a comma-separated list of absolute paths"

Comment: You were right. `/rooms/*/0.jpg` doesn't work.